# Remove key/value from map while iterating

Tags: groovy, dictionary

I'm creating a map like this:

```
def myMap = [:]
```

The map is basically an object for a key and an int for a value. When I iterate over the map, I decret the value, and if it's 0, I remove it. I already tried `myMap.remove()`, but I get a `ConcurrentModificationError` - which is fair enough. So I move on to using `it.remove()`, which is giving me weird results.

Basically, my code is this:

```
myMap.each {
    it.value--;

    if( it.value <= 0 )
        it.remove();
}
```

Simple enough. My problem is, if I print `myMap.size()` before and after the remove, they're the same. If I call `myMap.containsKey( key )`, it gives me `true`, the key is still in there.

*But*, if I print out the map like this:

```
myMap.each { System.out.println( "$it.key: $it.value" ); }
```

I get nothing, and calling `myMap.keySet()` and `myMap.values()` return empty.

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should be a bit more efficient than [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672262/remove-key-value-from-map-while-iterating/7672307#7672307) (because you only need to iterate over the map once). Unfortunately, it is also pretty verbose

```
def map = [2:1, 3:4]
def iterator = map.entrySet().iterator()

while (iterator.hasNext()) {

  if (iterator.next().value - 1 <= 0) {
    iterator.remove()
  }
}

// test that it worked
assert map == [3:4]
```

Comment: Hehe, you beat me to the iterator method ;-)

Comment: you've an extra ) in there, and it won't actually remove anything, but that's what I was looking for, thanks :)

Comment: @tim_yates even a blind squirrel finds a nut every once in a while

Answer (score 6):

Can you do something like this:

```
myMap = myMap.each { it.value-- }.findAll { it.value > 0 }
```

That will subtract one from every value, then return you a new map of only those entries where the value is greater than zero.

You shouldn't call the `remove` method on a Map `Entry`, it is supposed to be a private method used internally by the Map ([see line 325 for the Java 7 implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java)), so you calling it yourself is getting the enclosing Map into all sorts of bother (it doesn't know that it is losing entries)

Groovy lets you call private methods, so you can do this sort of trickery behind the back of the Java classes

#### Edit -- Iterator method

Another way would be:

```
myMap.iterator().with { iterator ->
  iterator.each { entry ->
    entry.value--
    if( entry.value <= 0 ) iterator.remove()
  }
}
```

Comment: ah, groovy and private... do you know why `containsKey()` still returns true even if the `keySet()` is empty? do you have a way that doesn't create a new map (I'm like that :D)?

Comment: I have it working using `for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Object, Integer>> it = myMap.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();)` but, well, that's reallly long :)

Comment: HashMap keeps an internal cache of key hashes (for containsKey calls) separately to where AbstractMap keeps its Set of keys.  So pulling items out of the map in this way is going to lead to some pretty odd results ;-)