# Groovy remove value from collection

Tags: java, groovy

In groovy is there a specific way to remove a value from a collection. For example I have a list of form fields but two of them are hidden fields and I'm trying to figure out how to remove them from the collection. The two parameters I'm trying to remove are **salesKey** and **topicSelection**.  Groovy newbie so code samples are most helpful

```
request.requestParameterMap.collect { key, value -> "$key: ${value[0].string}" }.join("\n")
key.remove("salesKey")
key.remove("topicSelection")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use findAll:

```
request.requestParameterMap.findAll { key, value -> 
    !( key in ["salesKey", "topicSelection"] )
}
```

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates that works. Except the value is producing a blank result for me here's what I have **request.requestParameterMap.findAll { key, value -> 
    !( key in ["salesKey", "topicSelection"] ? value.toString() : null }** )
}

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672262/remove-key-value-from-map-while-iterating).

Also, depending on your specific aims, there are a couple of other ways to remove a pair, including `dropWhile` (which is more or less iterating over your data struct) and `minus` (which isn't so much removing a pair as creating a new structure without the specified pair). Official doc [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html).

Comment: Sorry I'm a newbie to groovy I'm not sure if I'm following. The fields in my form aren't the 0 index. Do I define a series of values than iterate through my collection. If you have a code sample that would be amazing!